# Unity 3.5 to Unity 4.5.4

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, ios8

I am trying to update my old Unity xCode (Unity 3.5) project to Unity (4.5.4).  The app will crash using this method po:

> UnitySendMessage([className UTF8String], [methodNameName UTF8String], nil);

Help me, please.

Comment: Am sorry I can fix that issue , Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Unity (4.5.4), they are using char parameter like this:

```
    (UnitySendMessage(const char* obj, const char* method, const char* msg);)
```

So we want change the call like this:

```
    UnitySendMessage("className", "methodNameName" , "Nil");
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you should use the latest version of unity this year, and delete old version, so no issues! (i think...)

Comment: please give the exact version number